# How to simulate a red wine stain?

Tags: product-photography, still-life

I want to make a picture of a wine stain on a couch without ruining my couch.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: We've got questions like [How do I work with ice and a glass bottle for a product shoot?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/15733/how-do-i-work-with-ice-and-a-glass-bottle-for-a-product-shoot) with good answers; this seems to be in the same vein.

Answer (score 7):

#### Use Real Wine and Fake Couch

**If** you can find a piece of fabric which matches your couch...

- Stain the fabric
- Take one of the cushions from the sofa
- Remove the cushion cover (often easier said than done)
- Put a plastic bag around the cusion
- Wrap the stained fabric round the cushion
- Place the cushion and shoot away

... just an idea